# Problems with Python installation and Pycharm virtual environments

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I've been using PyCharm for a while now, when I first started using it python 3.7 was the latest release so I used that, everything worked fine (~8 different projects).

However, the latest version of Django requires python 3.8 or later so I finally updated and installed 3.11.

I'm having some problems setting up my Pycharm projects with python 3.11 (my system can't import Django even though it's installed, I think it stems from the project not being in a venv but I've tried to add it into one).I've installed python 3.11 in the default location, the same place python 3.7 was installed but when I choose a python interpreter (screenshot below) many of them are invalid. I also notice that many of my other projects (`FaceComparison` as an example) are using a python 3.7 that itself is within a virtual environment, within the `Scripts` folder by the looks of it.

Should I have installed python 3.11 in a virtual environment? Whenever I try and set up a new project and use a python 3.11 interpreter, a) it's got `(DjangoTesting)` in it - not sure why? and it also isn't in a virtual environment.

I've read many questions about Pycharm, virtual environments and followed Pycharms guide on setting them up but I'm still having problems with my Django installation (`ImportError: Couldn't import Django ... Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?`), which leads me to believe I'm not creating a virtual environment properly, even though I've started a fresh project and followed PyCharms vitrual environment steps a few times!

If I delete python 3.11 and start again is there a better way/place to install it?

Finally, apologies for the poor question, I'm just not sure of the exact problem!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, Pycharm was still using my other version of python (python 3.7) as the system interpreter.

What I had to do was:

1. Ctrl + Alt + S to get to settings
2. Click "Add Interpreter" in the top right
3. The "Add Local Interpreter"
4. Then in the left hand panel of the resulting window select "System Interpreter"
5. Change that to python 3.11
6. Click OK

Not sure why but for some reason that then allowed me to set up virtual environments properly with my project